# Puedo comparar dos listas en vb .net?

Tags: vb.net

Al cargar mi formulario, traigo información de la base de datos y la inserto en una lista, mediante un timer voy consultando posibles cambios, es posible comparar las dos listas para determinar los cambios incluido si aumenta o disminuya el tamaño y poder saber que items se cambiaron..

```
Private Sub Pedidos_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ModRestaurante.Restaurant.CreaGrupoMesero(Me.BarraNavegacionPedidos)
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT Mesero FROM RE_MESAS ORDER BY Mesero ASC"
    Dim dt As DataTable = AbrirTabla(Conexion, sql)
    For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        listaMeseroInMesas.Add(dt.Rows(i).ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

En el timer

```
  Dim sql As String = "SELECT Mesero FROM RE_MESAS ORDER BY Mesero ASC"
  Dim dt As DataTable = SMT_AbrirTabla(Conexion, sql)
  Dim NuevaLista As New List(Of String)
  For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
      NuevaLista.Add(dt.Rows(i).ToString)
  Next
  'Aqui iria la comparación ?
```

Comment: ¿Puedes dar ejemplos concretos de valores en las 2 listas y el resultado esperado en cada caso?

Answer (score 3):

Hay una manera de saber qué elementos están en una colección y no en otra..

El código para hacerlo sería algo así:

```
Dim SoloEnLaPrimeraColeccion As List(Of String) = Coleccion1.Except(Coleccion2).ToList()
```

Para más ejemplos podés mirar acá:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Creo que es imposible hacerlo de esta manera, la comparación se realiza sobre los datos diferentes, el problema es que estos pueden ser iguales en varios registros por ende no tendría efecto la comparación...                         Ej. Lista1 {1,1,2,3,4,5,5}     --    Lista2 {1,2,3,4,4,5,5 }.  la lisra 2 ha cambiado con respecto a la lista 1, pero NO encuentra diferencias por los valores que contienes, espero haberme hecho entender.. XD

Comment: No estaba muy claro eso en la pregunta. El código que te pasé permite saber si se agregó o quitó un elemento con respecto a la primera lista. Ahora, si lo que querés es comparar el elemento "n" de la primer lista con el elemento "n" de la otra y fijarte si cambio, no te queda otra que recorrer la lista elemento por elemento.